# add array values of hidden input through js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden input in a form as follows:

```
<form id="su" action="su.php"  method="POST" onsubmit ="sendQuestions(event)">
    <input type ='hidden' name ="questions[]" id = "questions"/>
    <button type="submit" >Generate Quiz</button>
</form>


function sendQuestions(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    let form = document.getElementById('su')
    let ques = document.getElementById('questions')

    var x = [5,10]
    ques.value = x;
    form.submit();

}
```

when I send this up to the server (PHP) and print out the $_POST array I get:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5,10
        )

)
```

is there a way to get:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of the `questions` input to "5,10" and not an array.

To solve your problem, you can:

In your PHP server use `explode` as follows to divide the array values and thus return what you want:

$questions would be the value of the field in your `$_POST`.

```
explode(",", $questions)
```

Or, you can dynamically create the inputs through this script, so it will correctly distribute the values in each input.

```
var array = [5,10];
var form = document.getElementById('su');

generateInputsWithArray('questions', array, form);

//Dynamically create the inputs
function generateInputsWithArray(inputName, data, parent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = inputName + "[]";
        input.value = data[i];
        
        parent.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```